# FileUtils public class method to rename an existed file when copying

Tags: ruby, standard-library

On `FileUtils` class (Ruby StdLib), among the class methods such as `FileUtils.cp`, `FileUtils.cp_r` `FileUtils.mv` etc., there is none providing optional renaming of the file, when the destination file exists.
I want to utilize the `FileUtils.cp_r` method and do some changes to `FileUtils` to support this behaviour.

Is this a good approach, or should I just implement my own `FileUtils.cp_r`?

**Update**:
I have checked the Rubinius source of `FileUtils.cp_r`, and found it calls `FileUtils.copy_entry`. I find it may be error prone to redefine a library method. So I opt to implement a custom recursively copy methods (which will rename an existed file).

Comment: You can use [`Dir::glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) to traverse a directory tree.

Comment: `Metaprogramming` is a colloquial term, and moreover, renaming files is orthogonal to it.

Answer (score 1):

try this out in irb

```
f = File.open('test.rb', 'w+')
  => #<File:test.rb>
irb(main):002:0> File.rename(f, "temp.rb")
  => 0
```